# Instantiating a 2D vector with a set of pairs as cell value

Tags: c++, vector

I'm struggling to instantiate a 2D vector (vector< vector >), containing a set of pairs.

My failing approach looks like this (where X, Y are integers and represent the vector dimensions):

```
vector< vector< set< pair<int, int> > > > 
       velocities (X, vector<int>(Y, set < pair<int, int> >));
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
./test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./test.cpp:8:70: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
  vector< vector< set< pair<int, int> > > > velocities (X, vector<int>(Y, set < pair<int, int> >));
                                                                      ^
./test.cpp:8:96: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  vector< vector< set< pair<int, int> > > > velocities (X, vector<int>(Y, set < pair<int, int> >));
```

When executing the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int X = 10, Y = 10;
    vector< vector< set< pair<int, int> > > > velocities (X, vector<int>(Y, set < pair<int, int> >));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: I added the compiler error and an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want is:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::set<std::pair<int, int> > > > 
   velocities (X, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<int, int>>>(Y));
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/iRMfmH)